# VIM plugin NERDTree unable to handle subfolder name with matching parenthese

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I met a problem with the NERDTree plugin while using VIM. It seems that NERDTree cannot handle some folder properly, if there are matching parenthese in the folder name, such as "[D]2015", "(t)", "foo[bar]", etc..

I can view its containing files by an **O** or **X** command on its parent folder within the NERDTree window, while **o** and **x** on this folder have no effect. If I just stay within the NERDTree window, I find no way to access/edit files in such a folder.

I can reach the contents in such a folder using ":Explorer" with netrw, or using command-line or external shell. However, I wonder *if there are some tricks to fix this problem within the scope of NERDTree.*

I met this problem on win7 (32bit) first.
My NERDTree plugin is a zip clone of the latest version(4.2.0) from its repository on github, last modified at 2014.11.20.
My VIM version is 7.4, the one from VIM's offical website. The beginning of its version info is as follows:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 10 2013 14:38:33)
>   MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
>   Compiled by mool@tororo
>   Big version with GUI. ...

I also checked it on Ubuntu-14.04 (64bit) and found the same problem with NERDTree.

I read the NERDTree's reference manual and found some information in its change log of 4.1.0, bugfixes part:

> - fix some win32 path escaping issues. Thanks to Stephan Baumeister, Ricky, jfilip1024, and Chris Chambers

but I am not sure whether this is relevant or not.

By the way, the option **NERDTreeHijackNetrw** makes me confused. I let "g:NERDTreeHijackNetrw=0" but it seems have no effect.

Comment: There is a bug report https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/391

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now I know it's not my fault and I will find ways  outside nerdtree.